# Instagram - How to programmatically scroll to load Followers/Followings

Tags: javascript, jquery, cefsharp

I am working on getting ALL the **Followers/Following** list from an Instagram (IG) Profile webpage. I am using CefSharp.WinForms (C#) and after loading the IG page I inject jQuery successfully using the ExecuteScriptAsync( "..." ) from the CefSharp.WinForms.

Using $('div[role="dialog"]') I have access to the Instagram Followers Popup Window (div) that shows up once you click on the Followers link.

Unfortunately, I have not find the proper way to simulate the scroll/wheel scroll/etc that triggers this div to load more followers once you scroll till the last current list.

Any idea? Trick? code? (preferably with jQuery but could be dom/js native too)

[image]

Comment: You can use js .scrollBy() method on the followers container

Answer (score 4):

For scroll moving in chrome console, this script works well...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('isgrP')[0].scrollTop=document.getElementsByClassName('isgrP')[0].scrollTop+document.getElementsByClassName('isgrP')[0].scrollHeight
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
jQuery('#elementId').bind('scroll', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).innerHeight() >= jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        //code to get followers list
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Aman but I do not need to get the followers list, I already know how to do that with C# once the list is loaded. What I need is to Load more followers dynamically. I need to force the SCROLL amd so trigger the page to load MORE followers... once I know how to do this I will find out how to do it infinitely until the WHOLE FOLLOWERS LIST is loaded. Right now I just need to find out how to simulate the scroll and get a new batch of users.

Comment: Thats what i answered, you can bind the scroll event and whenever user scrolls the list, this function will be invoked.

Comment: Are you asking to dynamically load objects in your list view, whenever the user scrolls, at a time user can see upto 10 followers ?

Comment: I need a CODE who fire the page to load load more users (followers). This only fire when you scroll with the mouse wheel or page-down, or page-end.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not find the proper way to ***simulate*** the scroll/wheel scroll/etc that ***triggers*** this div to load more followers once you scroll till the last current list.

Question: HOW TO SIMULATE the SCROLL... no how to bind it ... but how to TRIGGER IT.
I already solved it... will publish the solution later on tonight.